# Internet Explorer iframe JavaScript access denied

Tags: javascript, iframe, internet-explorer-9

I have a webpage on domain `www.example.com` that has an `<iframe>` with a page `test.html` from `sub.example2.com`. `test.html` includes a JavaScript from another domain:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When I open `www.example.com` then I get an access denied error for that JavaScript.

What's the reason for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to [the "Same Origin" security policy](http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy).

> The “Same Origin” policy limits the access of one window to another.
>
> The reason behind that is security. If you have blabla.com in one
>   window and gmail.com in another one, then you’d not want a script from
>   blabla.com to access or modify your mail or run actions in context of
>   gmail on your behalf.
>
> The essence of the Same Origin policy can be formulated as: windows
>   can work in contexts of each other only if they are from same
>   protocol://domain:port, or, shortly, from same origin.